# How to disable in-page Facebook chat for good?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I know you can go in Options > Go Offline. But since I use Pidgin to connect to Facebook Chat, it keeps coming online again. I only want to use it in pidgin. How to remove it from the Facebook web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only

```
facebook.com##DIV[id="pagelet_sidebar"]
```

in Adblock worked for me in the latest version of Facebook

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure there is no official way of doing this.  However, if you install AdBlock you could block the chat div from appearing by adding this custom rule:

`facebook.com##DIV[id="pagelet_presence"]`

- [AdBlock for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)
- [AdBlock for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)

Answer (score 2):

This works with adblock and chrome:

```
facebook.com##DIV[id="pagelet_chat"]
```